# imported csv to dataframe objects not recognized

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have imported multiple csv files from a folder. First I created a list of all the csv files in the folder and then I provide the length of the list to my function.

The csv files have rows with different column lengths so that is why I think I have to use readlines.

The problem is that when I try to filter the DataFrame the values are not recognized.

I saved it to a sqlite table and pulled it in to R and a value that looks like  "H"

appears to be like this in r  ---  "\"H\""

How can I prevent those extra characters from being added to my object "H"

Or do I have another problem?

```
x = []
count = 0
while (count < len(filelist) ):
    for file in  filelist:  
        filename = open(filelist[count])
        count = count + 1
        for line in filename.readlines():
            x.append(line.split(','))

df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

For example I am just trying to create a mask. But I am getting all False. The DataFrame appears to contain "H"?

```
data['V1'] == "H"
```

Comment: You don't need the outer ```while``` loop, the ```for file in  filelist:``` will stop iterating when the list is exhausted.  https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements.  don't forget to close your file, or use a ```with``` statement

Comment: Please include an example of the input - a few lines of the one of the files.

Comment: use `pd.read_csv()` to create separate df for each csv and then use `pd.concat()`

Comment: @wwii  sample: [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ACEO/AQU20080302.chart)

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Maybe a ```DataFrame``` is the wrong data type.  You have asked three questions.  Which do you want answered?

Comment: Filter out the rows by the first column, "H" , "R" , "S", "E" ,"F"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df_list =[]
file_list = []
path = 'file_path'
for file in file_list:
    df_name = 'df_%s' %file
    df_list.append(df_name)
    ('df_%s' % file) = pd.read_csv(path+file)

new_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Comment: pd.read.csv give this error "tokenizing data. C error: Expected 64 fields in line 11, saw 92'

Answer (score 0):

Answer: This code fixed the problem by removing the quotes throughout. Now the mask works.

```
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    df.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[:, i].str.replace('"', '')
```